# Adaptive background subtraction with motionless objects in processing

Tags: processing, background-subtraction, video-tracking

I would like to get a background subtraction method for outdoor conditions, capable of gradually adjust itself to environment light variations but with the capacity of revealing a presence even that is not in motion.

The problem with adaptive opencv background subtraction methods is that they are only capable to detect a presence when it is moving. On the other hand, old background subtraction methods do not work when the conditions of light are not always the same.

In order to get this I’ve modified the Golan Levin’s method in the video library of Processing (actual frames are compared with a first initial frame), setting a certain low difference threshold.

I therefore assume that all changes over that threshold are due to presence (persons, animals, etc), and changes below this are due to progressive light conditions, and I put this changed pixel in the background’s pixels array.

```java
/* auto-updating background part*/
diferencia = diffR+diffG+diffB;
if (diferencia<minDif)  backgroundPixels[i]=video.pixels[i];
```

That’s not working satisfactorily, image gets dirty, far off from being homogenous. Any idea of how to achieve this would be extremely welcome.

I post the whole code, if it could be of some help. Thanks a lot for your time.

```java
import processing.video.*;

int numPixels;
int[] backgroundPixels;
Capture video;
int camSel=0;
int topDiff=763;
int unbralDif=120;
int mindDif=20;
boolean subtraction, lowSubtr;
PGraphics _tempPG;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480); 

  _tempPG=createGraphics(width, height);
  if (camSel==0)video = new Capture(this, width, height);
  else video = new Capture(this, width, height, Capture.list()[1]);

  video.start();  

  numPixels = video.width * video.height;
  backgroundPixels = new int[numPixels];
  loadPixels();
}

void draw() {
  if (video.available()) {
    video.read(); 
    video.loadPixels(); 

    int presenceSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) { 
      color currColor = video.pixels[i];
      color bkgdColor = backgroundPixels[i];

      int currR = (currColor >> 16) & 0xFF;
      int currG = (currColor >> 8) & 0xFF;
      int currB = currColor & 0xFF;

      int bkgdR = (bkgdColor >> 16) & 0xFF;
      int bkgdG = (bkgdColor >> 8) & 0xFF;
      int bkgdB = bkgdColor & 0xFF;

      int diffR = abs(currR - bkgdR);
      int diffG = abs(currG - bkgdG);
      int diffB = abs(currB - bkgdB);

      presenceSum += diffR + diffG + diffB;

      pixels[i] = 0xFF000000 | (diffR << 16) | (diffG << 8) | diffB;

      /* auto-updating background part*/
      int diferencia = diffR+diffG+diffB;
      //detect pixels that have change below a threshold
      if (lowSubtr && diferencia<mindDif) {
        /* substitute with them the backgound img array */
        backgroundPixels[i]=video.pixels[i];
      }
      /* end auto-updating background part*/
    }

    updatePixels();
  }
  subtraction=false;
}


void keyPressed() {
  if (keyPressed)startSubtr();
}

void startSubtr() {
  arraycopy(video.pixels, backgroundPixels);
  lowSubtr=true;
}


void actualizacion(int[] _srcArr, int[] _inputArr, int _ind) {
  for (int i=0; i<_srcArr.length; i++) {
    _srcArr[_ind]=_inputArr[i];
  }
}
```